# Need to import a txt file to Python and use it with this code (Convert input line to list, append it, and return value)

Tags: python, list, append, sudoku

I have been writing this code for about an hour now and I can't get the final step. I need to modify this code below. From what I've tried and read, it's somewhere in the first 3 lines (but the whole code may need to be modified). I need to convert each input line to a list, append it to the board list, and return a sudoku board at the end.

The output at the end should be `Enter the file for the initial S board ==>`; then I enter `board3.txt` (included at the end of the post) and get the diagram I made in this code.

```
def read_board(fn):
    board = []
    for line in open(fn,'r'):
        # FIXME

def print_board( board ):
    for r in range(0,9):
        if r%3 == 0:
            print '-'*25
        print '|',
        for c in range(0,9):
            print board[r][c],
            if c==2 or c==5:
                print '|',
            elif c==8:
                print '|'
    print '-'*25

def ok_to_add(row,col,num,board):
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = raw_input("Enter the file for the initial S board ==> ").strip()
    board = read_board(name)
    print_board(board)
```

`board3.txt`:

```
1 . . . 2 . . 3 7
. 6 . . . 5 1 4 .
. 5 . . . . . 2 9
. . . 9 . . 4 . .
. . 4 1 . 3 7 . .
. . 1 . . 4 . . .
4 3 . . . . . 1 .
. 1 7 5 . . . 8 .
2 8 . . 4 . . . 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `split` each line. It will automatically divide the line by whitespace and make it into a list for you.

```
def read_board(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as file:
        return [line.split() for line in file]
```

Comment: didn't work, line 22 in <module> and line 10 in print_board, type error 'none type' object is not sub scriptable. didn't work. I overwrote your statement on the very top first 3 lines. after comes def print_board(board): etc.

Comment: Forgot to return the board object once it's constructed. Try it again.